# Run time keeps expanding

Tags: ms-access

The code below starts with a second or less between each record and slowly increases until each record takes 15 seconds at the 500th record.  Memory went from 130 Mb to 430 Mb.  I have 5000 records to process so anything to speed this up would be appreciated.

[NOTE: Updating via RecordSet also expands and takes more time]

```
Public Sub Update_Main_Data()

Dim sql_Read   As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst_Read As DAO.Recordset, rst_Write As DAO.Recordset
Dim New_CMID As Integer, New_Lead As Integer, New_GI As Integer, New_PMO As Integer
Dim New_Dist As Integer, New_Phase As Integer, New_Type As Integer, New_Finance As Integer

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Qoute_Char = Chr(34)
Last_Number = Qoute_Char & "AF00379-001" & Qoute_Char
sql_Read = ""
sql_Read = sql_Read & "Select ID, Contract_Number, Project_Type, Old_Type, CM, Old_CM, "
sql_Read = sql_Read & "Contract_Lead, Old_Lead, GI_PM, Old_GI, MPO_PM, Old_MPO, "
sql_Read = sql_Read & "Distrib_Contact, Old_Dist, FinanceReplacementCPUC, Old_Finance, "
sql_Read = sql_Read & "Contract_Phase, Old_Phase from [tblTrue-UpMain1] "
sql_Read = sql_Read & "WHERE Contract_Number > " & Last_Number & " ORDER BY Contract_Number"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst_Read = db.OpenRecordset(sql_Read)


RecNum = 0
    
rst_Read.MoveFirst
Do Until rst_Read.EOF

    Starting_Time = Now()
    Time_Start = Timer()

    RecNum = RecNum + 1
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_CM) Then
        New_CMID = 0
    Else
        New_CMID = Nz(DLookup("CMID", "tblContractManagers1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_CM), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_Lead) Then
        New_Lead = 0
    Else
        New_Lead = Nz(DLookup("CMID", "tblContractManagers1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_Lead), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_GI) Then
        New_GI = 0
    Else
        New_GI = Nz(DLookup("ID", "tblGI-PM1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_GI), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_MPO) Then
        New_MPO = 0
    Else
        New_MPO = Nz(DLookup("ID", "tblPMO-PM1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_MPO), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_Dist) Then
        New_Dist = 0
    Else
        New_Dist = Nz(DLookup("ID", "tblDistContact1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_Dist), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_Phase) Then
        New_Phase = 0
    Else
        New_Phase = Nz(DLookup("ID", "tblContract_Phase1", "PhaseID = " & rst_Read!Old_Phase), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_Type) Then
        New_Type = 0
    Else
        New_Type = Nz(DLookup("ID", "tblContract_Types1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_Type), 0)
    End If
    
    If IsNull(rst_Read!Old_Finance) Then
        New_Finance = 0
    Else
        New_Finance = Nz(DLookup("ID", "tblFinanceReplacement1", "Old_ID = " & rst_Read!Old_Finance), 0)
    End If
   
    Main_String = ""
    Main_String = Main_String & "UPDATE [tblTrue-UpMain1] SET [tblTrue-UpMain1].CM = " & New_CMID
    Main_String = Main_String & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].Contract_Lead = " & New_Lead & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].GI_PM = " & New_GI
    Main_String = Main_String & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].MPO_PM = " & New_PMO & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].Distrib_Contact = " & New_Dist
    Main_String = Main_String & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].Contract_Phase = " & New_Phase & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].Project_Type = " & New_Type
    Main_String = Main_String & ", [tblTrue-UpMain1].FinanceReplacementCPUC = " & New_Finance
    Main_String = Main_String & " WHERE ((([tblTrue-UpMain1].ID)=" & rst_Read!ID & "));"
    DoCmd.RunSQL Main_String
    
    Ending_Time = Now()
    Time_End = Timer()
    
    Curr_Num = Qoute_Char & rst_Read!Contract_Number & Qoute_Char
    Time_String = ""
    Time_String = Time_String & "INSERT INTO Contract_Time1 ( Contract_Number, "
    Time_String = Time_String & "End_Time, Start_Time, Elasped_Time )"
    Time_String = Time_String & "SELECT " & Curr_Num & " as New_Num, #" & Ending_Time
    Time_String = Time_String & "# As New_End , #" & Starting_Time & #" as New_Start,  "
    Time_String = Time_String & Time_End - Time_Start & " as new_Time"
    DoCmd.RunSQL Time_String
    
    
    rst_Read.MoveNext
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you show `Cmd.RunSQL Time_String` and not `DoCmd.RunSQL Time_String`?

Comment: I mis-typed it at first.  The running version, and the edited code has DoCmd.

Comment: Maybe all those repeated DLookup() calls are using memory. I have read something about domain aggregate function establishing a data connection which persists until procedure ends. 5000 loops would be a lot of connections. Do a test with code that loops through 5000 records without any DLookup()s or UPDATE or INSERT, just a `Debug.Print rst_Read!Old_CM`.

Comment: Maybe provide sample raw data and desired result as text tables or post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- I'll let you know the result.

Comment: Do you know how to close the data connections?

Comment: Nope. Ending procedure may be only way. I can't find any discussions now, just vague memory. Never had this issue.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but it's not very satisfactory.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest: expand your input query to include all tables that you DLookup from, using LEFT JOINs. Then you can read all data directly from `rst_Read`. -- If you write the query result into a temp table, you may even be able to run your updates with a single UPDATE query, not needing a recordset loop at all.

Comment: Thanks, Andre -- I'll try that tomorrow.

I can do that as 2 queries -- one to select all the data (from Main and related tables) into a temp table; and another to update Main from the temp table.

Comment: any linked tables? or is this a single database?